# Array formula where i need to find weighted average

Tags: arrays, excel, array-formulas

I am trying to find a weighted avg score for each member. So column A for me is the member list for each loan. Column BC is where scores are. I will weight them by the principal balance and that is column K. I put the unique member numbers in column BF. I tried the formula below but it doesn't work, I appreciate any suggestions:

```
=IF($A$6:$A$46375=BF6,$BC$6:$BC$46375*$H$6:$K$46375)/SumIF($A$6:$A$46375=BF6,$BC$6:$BC$46375))
```

Comment: change `$H$6` to `$K$6` may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use Sumproduct on the numerator:

   `SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$46375=BF6)*$BC$6:$BC$46375*$H$6:$K$46375)`
2. The SUMIF has a typo, You do not use the `=` in that manner in a SUMIF:

   `SUMIF($A$6:$A$46375,BF6,$BC$6:$BC$46375)`

So together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$46375=BF6)*$BC$6:$BC$46375*$H$6:$K$46375)/SUMIF($A$6:$A$46375,BF6,$BC$6:$BC$46375)
```

It is not a CSE array formula.  It does not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thank you, the only issue left is this part i believe, ($A$6:$A$46375=BF6) that part of the formula doesn't recognize so it returns the whole value as 0

Comment: Got it, i trimmed BF6 and now it worked, thanks a bunch, i love you.

Answer (score 0):

array formula

write
`=sum(if(A6:A46375=BF6,BC6:BC46375*K6:K46375,0)/sum(if(A6:A46375=BF6,BC6:BC46375,0))`

then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>